# How to map a single table to multiple tables in Hibernate?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, entity-relationship

I have a common `Address` table that I would like to map to several other tables like `Owner`, `Customer`, `Purchase Order` etc. Is there a way to do this in Hibernate ?

The current approach that I am using is to embed the `Address` entity in the other tables using `@Embeddable` with Address class. Is there a better way to do it ?

Also, I would like to cascade delete the row entry from the Address table whenever any related row in `Customer` , `Owner` etc gets deleted.

Address table -

```
@Embeddable
@Data
public class Address{
 .....
}
```

Customer table -

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Customer{

   @Id
   private Long id;

   @Embedded
   private Address address;
}
```

Owner table -

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Owner{

   @Id
   private Long id;

   @Embedded
   private Address address;
}
```

Comment: When you say "map" do you mean to link those 2 tables with a foreign key?

Comment: Foreign key would be ideal approach but I don't think it will work here since each record in address table can either have FK from the 3 other tables and not all of them and thus the FK will of the other 2 tables will be empty. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @Jens Where does the OneToOne mapping goes ?

Comment: `@OneToOne` replaces @Embedded

Comment: @Jens So its just a unidirectional mapping from Customer, Owner tables ? No mapping info in maintained on the Address side ?

Comment: If you neeit you should addd it

Comment: @BoudhayanDev do you want a bidirectional relationship?

Comment: @Anthony Yes. There are certain queries where I would like to reach the related (mapped) entity from the address entity. Bi-directional relationship would be useful in that.